# not able to mount mmcblk0p2 after using etcher?

Tags: sd-card, raspbian-lite

I have flashed 16gb SD card with Raspbian lite using etcher for Pi 3B+.
After successful flashing the boot partition is visible but the rootfs partition shows the following error
[image]

what should I do ?

Comment: Where did the picture you included come from? What did you try (on the Pi)?

Comment: `etcher for Pi 3B+` etcher only comes in Windows, Mac and Linux (x86 or x64) - there is no etcher for Pi 3B+

Comment: Why don't you try doing it again with `dd` `sudo dd if=/path/to/raspbian.img of=/dev/mmcblk0 status=progress`?